# Cannot start httpd: Segmentation fault in apachectl

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, httpserver

I am getting below error when i try to run httpd.

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./apachectl -k start
./apachectl: line 78: 22059 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $HTTPD $ARGV
```

This is the apachectl startup script lines are as:

```
74 if [ "x$ARGV" = "x" ] ; then
 75     ARGV="-h"
 76 fi
 77 
 78 case $ARGV in
 79 start|stop|restart|graceful|graceful-stop)
 80     $HTTPD -k $ARGV
 81     ERROR=$?
 82     ;;
 83 startssl|sslstart|start-SSL)
 84     echo The startssl option is no longer supported.
 85     echo Please edit httpd.conf to include the SSL configuration settings
 86     echo and then use "apachectl start".
 87     ERROR=2
 88     ;;
```

Checked the messages on /var/log

```
Mar 21 09:45:11 localhost kernel: httpd[22059]: segfault at 8 ip 00000039d360b453 sp 00007fff7e5e80a0 error 4 in ld-2.12.so[39d3600000+20000]
Mar 21 09:45:11 localhost abrtd: Directory 'ccpp-2016-03-21-09:45:11-22059' creation detected
Mar 21 09:45:11 localhost abrt[22060]: Saved core dump of pid 22059 (/apps/httpd-2.2.22/bin/httpd) to /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-03-21-09:45:11-22059 (1904640 bytes)
Mar 21 09:45:11 localhost abrtd: Executable '/apps/httpd-2.2.22/bin/httpd' doesn't belong to any package
Mar 21 09:45:11 localhost abrtd: 'post-create' on '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-03-21-09:45:11-22059' exited with 1
Mar 21 09:45:11 localhost abrtd: Corrupted or bad directory '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-03-21-09:45:11-22059', deleting
```

Do I need to install something for "Executable '/apps/httpd-2.2.22/bin/httpd' doesn't belong to any package" error ? Sorry, am completely new to httpd and linux installations.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error but my Operating system was ubuntu. I checked error log in /var/log/syslog and there I found libphp5.6.so has some error like below.

Feb  7 11:57:45 Varun kernel: [  698.096661] apache2[3897]: segfault at 841f4f ip 00007f979593f3ae sp 00007ffca776ac40 error 4 in libphp5.6.so[7f97956d5000+3b3000]

Apache normal log files were not showing above error.
So I disabled php5.6 via `sudo a2dismod php5.6 && sudo service apache2 reload`
After that apache worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix this. I commented this line in httpd.conf

```
Include conf/mod-jk.conf
```

and saw no error. Checked mod-jk.conf is having entry for mod_jk.so. Tried changing mod_jk.so and things worked fine. 
Seems like the version of mod_jk.so was a wrong one.